# What is a syntax of transferring data from listView (Visual studio, c#) to another database?

Tags: c#, mysql, listview, visual-studio-2012

I have data sent from SQL Server in my C# application. Data contains in a listView (in 2 columns: pay_type and pay_amount). Here is code how's it done:

```
private bool isDataSetValid(DataSet ds)
{
    return (ds != null) && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0;
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            try
            {
                DataSet ds = this.getDataToTable();
                if (ds != null)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                    this.listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(
                                new String[] {dr[0].ToString(),dr[1].ToString() }))

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

And here I'm trying to send this data to another database:

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO SALES_TABLE(pay_type, pay_amount) 
VALUES (" + listView1.Items.ToString() + "," + listView1.Items.ToString() + ");";
```

What should I use instead of `listView1.Items.ToString()` in order to MySQL command work properly? 
Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't insert like that. In sql such thing can be achieved by select into clause but in Your case it won't help. Go with a foreach loop like below:

```
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            foreach (var item in listView1.Items)
            {
                string firstValue = item.SubItem.First();
                string secondValue = item.Subitem.Last();
                String insertSQL = @"INSERT INTO SALES_TABLE(pay_type, pay_amount) 
                                VALUES (@val1 , @val2)";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1",firstValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", secondValue);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            } 
        }
```

PLEASE NOTE

Never use a string to add parameters to the query. It makes Your application very vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: DownVote, could You explain ?

Comment: How can a `ListViewItem` be casted to a `string[]` ?

Comment: There is an unhandled exception which says that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." This line:
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", values[0]);`

Comment: Only possible reason for NullReferenceException is that values[0] is null.

Answer (score 2):

`listView1.Items` is of type `ListViewItemCollection`, that is, a collection of `ListViewItem`.

Now, for each `ListViewItem` in this collection, you want to insert a row in your `SALES_TABLE`.

The `ToString()` method on a collection will not print out each element, nor is something you can use in this case.

Let's start by creating our base string:

```
StringBuilder insertSQL = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO SALES_TABLE(pay_type, pay_amount) VALUES ");
```

Then, we have to iterate over our `ListViewItem` and append each item to our `insertSQL` string

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in view.Items)
{
    //I am using LINQ First() and Last() to get the first and the second items, provided you have only 2 elements on the list
    insertSQL.AppendFormat("({0}, {1}),", item.SubItems.First(), item.SubItems.Last());
}
```

Lastly, we have to remove the last trailing `,`:

```
insertSQL.Remove(insertSql.Length - 1, 1);
```

Final code:

```
private string CreateInsertSQL(ListView view) {
   StringBuilder insertSQL = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO SALES_TABLE(pay_type, pay_amount) VALUES ");
   foreach(ListViewItem item in view.Items)
   {
       insertSQL.AppendFormat("({0}, {1}),", item.SubItems.First(), item.SubItems.Last());
   }
   insertSQL.Remove(insertSQL.Length - 1, 1);
   return insertSQL.ToString();
}
```

This will generate a `string` like the following one:

```
"INSERT INTO SALES_TABLE(pay_type, pay_amount) VALUES (type1, amount1),(type2,amount2),(type3,amount3)"
```

You may call this method like this:

```
string insertCommand = CreateInsertSQL(this.listView1);
```

**NOTE**: I am using a `StringBuilder` for performance reasons, but you may use a normal `string`.